# Tab change event slow in mahapp metro

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabitem, mahapps.metro

I'm using wpf with mahapps metro for the UI. I saw that when I load some values in a DataGrid from a function, and so I'll open the tab where this value's stored, the delay time is about of 3-4 seconds. There's a way to speed up all?

Comment: DataGrids alone can take a few seconds to render depending on the amount of data being accessed. Are you sure that your issue is directly related to Mahapps? With datagrids try enabling row visualization as this can help performance by deferring the rendering process.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a problem of Mahapp. How to enable this row visualization?

Comment: <datagrid EnableRowVirtualization="True" .../>

Comment: it would be worth posting some of your code, and include detail regarding the data (e.g. number of rows/columns), the data provider, etc

Comment: with the virtualization the situation is better, other cheat for improve the speed?

Comment: it would be worth posting some of your code, and include detail regarding the data (e.g. number of rows/columns), the data provider, etc

Comment: You could also consider pagination, splitting you grid into multiple pages e.g. Page 1 would contain records 1-100, page 2 would contain 101-200..